# can't see anonymous type values without using .FirstOrDefault() ?

Tags: c#, linq

I m using the following LINQ query which is returning an anonymous type. I can't see values in debug if I don't use `.FirstOrDefault()`

Why is that ? My result set needs to be multiple rows and I also want to see results while debugging. If don't use .FirstOrDefault() in debug it shows some expressions not real values (Image below). Please help what I should do if I want to get multiple rows and also want to see values while debugging.

[image]

```
 var results5 = (from acc in context.AccountSet
                        join contact in context.ContactSet
                            on acc.PrimaryContactId.Id equals contact.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            _contactId = contact.Id,
                            _accountId = acc.Id
                        }
                            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.FirstOrDefault()`you are collecting  the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. Which is of the Same type in the collection(let it be a Collection of `userAccounts`). If the result includes `N` number of records then Use `.ToList()` to convert it into a List. Which will Give you `List<T>` where `T` is the Type of Object in the collection(example `List<userAccounts>`).

```
var results5 = (from acc in context.AccountSet
                        join contact in context.ContactSet
                            on acc.PrimaryContactId.Id equals contact.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            _contactId = contact.Id,
                            _accountId = acc.Id
                        }
                            ).ToList();
```

Then it will be visible like a List;

**Regarding attached image :**

To view the elements in the collection without using `.ToList()`, Expand that `+` There will be a `results View` and a refresh icon associated with it on its right side, Click on it. Then it will became expandable. And it shows you the items in the current result.

Comment: thanks. Can you give a hint why it was happening ? What trick .ToList() did  ? and what I was getting without using .ToList() ?

Comment: I read something which I dont exectly understood was it is not fetched until it is first used. may be .ToList() is its first use ?

Comment: @user576510 : Sorry, I don't get what you are asking in the second comment

Comment: @user576510 : i have some updates for you in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Linq` queries are lazily evaluated. (Most)`Linq` query methods returns an `Iterator`. iterator is only executed when you iterate through it using `ToList`, `foreach`,`ToArray` etc.

In your case, first one returns an iterator which is not materialized yet, but in the second case since you called `FirstOrDefault` which goes through the iterator and returns the First (or Default) element in the sequence, which is why you see a result.

Comment: Thanks Hari. Is there a way without using .ToList() or foreach or ToArray() I can get from Linq values. Is there a way of non-lazily evaluation ?

Comment: @user576510 sorry I was out for a while, you have to iterate to materialize it.